# javascript tab change on button click

Tags: javascript, html, tabs

I have this code and on Tab click, it is working fine, but I can't change tab from button click.

```
    var tabs = document.getElementById('icetab-container').children;
    var tabcontents = document.getElementById('icetab-content').children;

    var myFunction = function () {
        var tabchange = this.mynum;
        for (var int = 0; int < tabcontents.length; int++) {
            tabcontents[int].className = ' tabcontent';
            tabs[int].className = ' icetab';
        }
        tabcontents[tabchange].classList.add('tab-active');
        this.classList.add('current-tab');
    }


    for (var index = 0; index < tabs.length; index++) {
        tabs[index].mynum = index;
        tabs[index].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
    }
```

I tried this code :

```
    function changeView() {
        tabs[1].click(); // and 
        tabs[1].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
    }
```

What is the right way to do it?
This is the HTML code :

```
        <div class="codepen-container">
            <div id="icetab-container">
                <div class="icetab current-tab">Add Group <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                <div class="icetab">Add User <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
            </div>

                                <div class="col-md-offset-8 col-md-4 ">
                                    <button type="button" onclick="changeView()" Text="Save"class="btn btn-default" />
                                </div>
```

Comment: Please add HTML to your question. Where and how do you call the `changeView()` function?

Comment: <div class="codepen-container">
                <div id="icetab-container">
                    <div class="icetab current-tab">Add Group <i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                    <div class="icetab">Add User <i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                </div>
                    <div id="icetab-content">
                    </div>
                    <div id="user-tab" class="tabcontent">                     
                    </div>
                </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing now is adding a new click event listener fot the tab with 1 index, so user still need to click on it to get it working.

You just need to [call the `myFunction` with providing this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) with setting this.mynum to the index you want to be selected

```
function changeView() {
    myFunction.call({mynum: 1});
}
```

More readable is:

```
function changeView(index) {
    myFunction.call({mynum: index});
}
```

and you can call:

- changeView(0) for the first tab
- changeView(1) for second tab
- ...